# How to close sockets left open by a killed program?

Tags: sockets, pyzmq

I have a program (Python) that in some point uses

```
    zmq.Context.socket(zmq.REP)
```

and

```
    zmq.Context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
```

sockets but the problem is that when program is killed the sockets still can be found using:

```
    'ps aux | grep zmq'
```

command. So what can I do to make them disappear after program is killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to;

https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline

Only an application can close the sockets it is using, after the applications process is killed, the sockets should be automatically freed within a couple of minutes. Are you being patient enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SO_REUSEADDR to work around that problem

> SO_REUSEADDR  Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses
>   supplied in a bind(2) call should  allow reuse of local addresses. For
>   AF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind   except when there
>   is an active listening socket bound to the address. When the listen- 
>   ing socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a specific port then it is not
>   possible to bind  to this port for any local address. Argument is an
>   integer boolean flag.

This should anser most of your questions http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html